# How to upload URL-based mp3 file from the client to the node server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to upload a mp3 file to node server using fetch.

Is the below code correct way to do this?

```
 var song;
  toDataUrl('http://s5.qhres.com/static/465f1f953f1e6ff2.mp3', function(myBase64) {
    // console.log(myBase64); // myBase64 is the base64 string
    song = myBase64;
});

  fetch("/ffmpegserver/upload", {
    method: 'PUT',
    headers: { 'Accept': 'audio/mpeg', 'Content-Type': 'audio/mpeg' },
    body: song
  })
    .then(response => {
      console.log("Got response after uploading song:", response);
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log("Error in Firebase AC upload song: ", error);
    });
}
```

If so, how can I receive it and write the file as mp3 in the node server?

```
app.put("/ffmpegserver/upload", (req, res) => {
  var mp3SongName = "output/test.mp3";
  var mp3_file = fs.createWriteStream(mp3SongName);
// how to write the mp3 file?
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This code would need something on the client that would steam the audio into a buffer and then send that buffer to the node server.

Instead of that, I think the best option would be to send the url of the mp3 file to the node backend, and then use a library like axios to download the mp3 file and persist it somehow.